# How can I change the network dynamically in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a deep fully connected network.
I want to be able to change the structure of middle layers of the network dynamically.
What is the best way of doing that?

What I did right now is to create an output placeholder for my network. I thought I will create a network dynamically by using feed_dict. However, when I run it it says.

```
`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ... `
```

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow won't make this easy for you. Once you define the graph and open a session it's fixed. I believe you need to define a new graph, copy over your variables, and move on from there every time you want to alter the architecture. Kinda annoying for experimenting with this kind of stuff.

I have a friend/fellow researcher who's been experimenting with dynamic neural network architectures and is tackling this in pytorch, which has specific support for dynamically altering network architectures.

Comment: actually you can modify the graph after calling session, as long as you haven't called `finalize` on it